# Simplest custom serialization in Jackson?

Tags: json, jackson

I have an `EntityId` class that servers as a simple wrapper class to database identifiers.  The class already has methods for converting to and from a string representation.  I'd like to use this string representation of the `EntityId` in my JSON web resources.

What's the simplest to implement custom serialization for this simple type in Jackson?  I know I can write a custom serializer and deserializer, but I wondered if there might be an even simpler solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a method to serialize type as String, you can just add `@JsonValue` annotation like so:

```
public class MyClass {
  @JsonValue public String toString() { return "xxx"; }
}
```

Conversely, if there is a single-arg constructor that takes a `String`, `int` or `long` (or some Java type that Jackson can convert to from JSON Scalar type), you can add `@JsonCreator` annotation next to that constructor:

```
public class MyClass {
  @JsonCreator
  public MyClass(OtherPojo value) { // or use 'Map<String,Object>', extract data
      // ... 
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that should do it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One more addition -- `@JsonValue` works on any Jackson-serializable return type, not just Strings.